# When to use different ssis Lookup Cache options like no cache and partial cache

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

SSIS Lookup

It has been understand that the lookup cache increases the performance .What is the need of no cache and partial cache in the ssis look up component?

If i have a large data set which cache option is good?

Comment: Should be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes.aspx

Comment: Thank you this is a good blog!